# Getting second highest value using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have application history id and I want to get the second highest history Id using criteria. Currently I can only get either lowest or highest value using code shown below.

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("historyId"));
criteria.setMaxResults(1);
```

I would appreciate if anyone can direct me on how to get second highest value using hibernate criteria?

Comment: Set max results to 2 then take the second item of whatever is returned?

Comment: How would I be able to get it ?

Comment: Depends upon what the query returns. If it's an array, then maybe `result[1]`. If a list then maybe `result.get(1)`. Execute the query and see what is returned to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
criteria.addOrder(Order.desc("historyId"));
criteria.setFirstResult(1);
criteria.setMaxResults(1);
```

This resolved the issue

Comment: 2 or more employees have same max salary will not be listed by this query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setFirstResult](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Query.html#setFirstResult(int)) method for offset